# How design more graphical filters in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

How to design more Graphical filters in tableau desktop so I need filter should be the more attractive part in terms of beauty-ness and here am attaching the image for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can save your custom images as custom shape files and use them as clickable filters on your Tableau dashboard. 
Under "My Documents" folder you should have a "My Tableau Repository" folder in which you will find the Tableau shapes folder. Create a folder in the shapes folder, give it an appropriate name and start adding images to it, which you will be able to use in your vizzes.